# change the active Drupal 7 theme programmatically

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

What is the correct way to change the active Drupal 7 theme programmatically? I used `$custom_theme` in Drupal 6 but it is not working in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`hook_custom_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7):

```
function mymodule_custom_theme() {
  if ($some_condition_is_true) {
    return 'my_theme';
  }
}
```

If you need to base your selection on the path then the best way to go is to override the `theme callback` for particular menu router items. [See here for an example](http://www.snipplr.com/view/49976/).

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not sure what is the condition when you want to change the theme, but if you want to change the theme based on a url, node type, taxonomy term, view page etc then you can handle that using Context module which will do this for you and you don't even have to write a single line of code. Check this out: http://drupal.org/project/context

This is a very useful module and has nice integration with almost all famous modules like panels, omega theme, delta etc.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal variable `theme_default` is the one you have to set to switch theme using [variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) function.

```
variable_set('theme_default', 'your_theme_name');
```

You can change the default theme through a [hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) if you have a custom module already installed. Also make sure you call the code in [hook_install](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) to run it during install time in case you want to share your module with somebody else and want to change active theme during install time.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_N().
 */
function mymodule_update_7000() {
  $theme_list = array(
    'bootstrap',
    'mytheme',
    'shiny',
  );
  theme_enable($theme_list);
  $theme_default = 'mytheme';
  // The below code would change the default active theme to 'mytheme'
  variable_set('theme_default', $theme_default);
  $admin_theme = 'shiny';
  variable_set('admin_theme', $admin_theme);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While `variable_set()` will work for `hook_install()` or `hook_update_N()`, you should not use it within a module.  Calling `variable_set()` empties the cache_bootstrap table, which is a serious performance hit on busy sites.

I would recommend the [ThemeKey module](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) if you don't need the full power of Context. However, contexts are easily exportable for versioning, while as far as I know there is no way to export ThemeKey rules.